# intercept firebase-functions response (middleware)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

For my Google Assistant/Dialogflow project, I am trying to intercept every response my firebase-functions endpoint is sending back to Dialogflow. I can easily intercept the request, but the response gets built within several functions (one function for every Intent), and I don't want to include an interceptor in every function.

Is it possible to have a middleware or is there a callback provided when a response is send out, sort of a global interceptor for every response?

I have found the following in the Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#use_middleware_modules_with

However, I am unsure where this goes. Note that I am not using a custom express setup, but I am using the native implementation on firebase directly.

Answer (score 1):

serialize() method is called on conversation right before the response is sent back, so what you can do is to extend the conversation object(based on the library you are using) and overwrite the serialize method to do whatever you need to do. don't forget to call the original serialize method and return the value in your new method.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Dialog Flow with Firebase for your fulfilment, I am expecting you are also using `actions-on-google` package.

`serialize()` is a function which is called to generate the response. You can override this function and intercept the request and response. Try this code and thank me later.

```js
app.middleware((conv) => {
  const serializeCopy = conv.serialize;
  conv.serialize = () => {
    const response = serializeCopy.call(conv);
    console.log(conv.request, response);
    return response;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions does not expose any sort of middleware or interceptors for HTTP requests or responses.  You will have to build something yourself, probably with an Express app that you build yourself.  You can host an Express app on Cloud Functions.

Comment: Ah too bad there is no hook or something where I can intercept the response before it gets send out without building something custom.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something similar to intercept all conversations back and forth for logging purposes. I ended up writing a function that I use to send a conversation. For eg:

```
const intercept = (conv, sentence) => {
  //My Interceptor code
  conv.ask(sentence)
}
```

Now anytime I want to send a response, I would use:

```
intercept(conv, "Speak this")
```